# drag shape without fill

Tags: javascript, easeljs, createjs

I am trying to create an EaselJS app that lets me drag unfilled circles around the canvas - so instead of calling `beginFill` when I am setting up the `Shape` I would call `beginStroke`. I am running into the problem that if I don't fill the shape, I can only drag it when I am selecting the top left corner of the shape. When the shape is filled I can drag it by selecting anywhere within the shape. Is there a way I can make the unfilled shape drag the same way as the filled shape?

Comment: Have you tried filling it with a transparent color? I've never used EasyJS specifically, but with other libraries that has worked for me in the past.

Comment: Unfortunately, dragging in EaselJS uses mouse-opacity to determine hit tests (as do all mouse interactions). Making a fill fully transparent will not work, although you could use 1% or 2% opacity. The hitArea solution proposed by @derz is the best way to go.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Strokes and fills are necessary in EaselJS for masks. You could however assign an other `Shape` as `hitArea`:

```
 var shape = new createjs.Shape();
 shape.graphics.beginFill("#000000").drawCircle(0, 0, 40);

 draggableCircle.hitArea = shape;
```

Keep in mind that the hitArea-`Shape` doesn't have to be added to the stage and thus won't be visible.