# How to set the cursor in EaselJS, with mouseover enabled?

Tags: javascript, canvas, easeljs, createjs

How can I set the cursor for a canvas when using EaselJS?

After a lot of debugging, I managed to figure out the problematic code: `stage.enableMouseOver()`. I am using `stage.enableMouseOver()` because I need to be able to mouse over various elements placed on the stage. However, I've found that subsequently trying to set the cursor for the canvas fails to do anything. `stage.canvas.style.cursor = "text"` does nothing, as well as `stage.cursor = "text"`. However, `stage.canvas.style.cursor` works when `stage.enableMouseOver()` is commented out.

This doesn't work:

```js
var stage = new createjs.Stage("canvas");

stage.enableMouseOver(); // comment out this line to get it to work

$("button").click(function() {
  stage.canvas.style.cursor = "text";
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.createjs.com/easeljs-0.8.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="change-cursor">
  Use text cursor instead of default
</button>
<br>
<canvas id="canvas" width=100 height=100 style="background-color:whitesmoke"></canvas>
```

How can I get my chosen cursor to appear, without removing `stage.enableMouseOver()`?

---

Example that does work, but comments out `stage.enableMouseOver()`:

```js
var stage = new createjs.Stage("canvas");

// stage.enableMouseOver();

$("button").click(function() {
  stage.canvas.style.cursor = "text";
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.createjs.com/easeljs-0.8.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="change-cursor">
  Use text cursor instead of default
</button>
<br>
<canvas id="canvas" width=100 height=100 style="background-color:whitesmoke"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a `cursor`property available in EaselJS, check the example below:

```js
var stage = new createjs.Stage("canvas");
stage.cursor = 'text';
  
var bgShape = new createjs.Shape();
bgShape.graphics.beginFill("red").drawRect(0, 0, 100, 100);
stage.addChild(bgShape);

stage.enableMouseOver();
```

```css
#canvas {
  cursor: text;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.createjs.com/easeljs-0.8.1.min.js"></script>

<canvas id="canvas" width=100 height=100 style="background-color:whitesmoke"></canvas>
```

Comment: I already knew about `stage.cursor = "text";` but that didn't work for me. Does the cursor only work when my mouse is over a drawn shape? I could get it to work by drawing a background shape, then, but is there a way using `canvas.style.cursor`?

Comment: Yes, the 'mouseover' on canvas is only working if there is a shape, as it is using mouse-opacity to determine hit test. However the shape don't have to be added to the Stage, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29463306/drag-shape-without-fill/29470422#29470422
I think your canvas.style.cursor gets overwritten by EaselJS (not totally sure though).

Comment: If you just set `cursor: text;` via CSS it works fine, as only the inline-styles will be overwritten. ;-) Check my edit above.

Comment: So there is no way to get it to work using inline styles... ugh oh well, I'll go from here.

Comment: You could achieve more or less the same with just adding/removing a class to the canvas. :-)

Answer (score 1):

For those which are working with Animate CC, set the cursor before you enable mouse over:

```
stage.cursor="pointer";
stage.enableMouseOver(20);
```